# Global variable scope with event handler for dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, jquery-events

I want to change the behaviour of a Bootstrap dropdown based on a global state variable. If the `uiState` variable is `'normal'` when it is clicked, it should display the dropdown, but if it's in another state it should do something else. I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var uiState = 'normal';

    // Load HTML for word control from server
    var wordUiElement;
    $.get('/static/word_ui_element.html', function (data) {
        wordUiElement = data;
    });
   var nwords = 0;
   var testClickCounter = 0;

   // Make it so dropdowns are exclusively controlled via JavaScript
   $(document).off('.dropdown.data-api')

   $('#ui-add-word').click(function (event) {
       var control = wordUiElement.replace(/wx/g, 'w' + nwords.toString());
       $('#ui-spec').append(control);
       nwords++;
   });

   $('#ui-change-state').click(function (event) {
       if (uiState === 'word_select') {
           uiState = 'normal';
       } else {
           uiState = 'word_select';
       }
       console.log(uiState);
   });

    $('#ui-spec').on('click', '.dropdown .dropdown-toggle', function (event) {
        if (uiState === 'normal') {
            $(this).dropdown('toggle');
        }
        else {
            testClickCounter ++;
            console.log(testClickCounter);
        }
    });

});
```

However, when the dropdowns are dynamically created, their behaviour seems to be fixed based on what the `uiState` variable was when the dropdown was created.

This means that if a dropdown was created when the `uiState` variable was set to `'normal'`, no matter what `uiState` is when it's clicked, it will always show or hide the dropdown. On the other hand if the dropdown was created when `uiState` was `'word_select'`, it will always increment and log `testClickCounter`. It's as if the if statement in the handler is evaluated once when the dropdown is created and preserves whatever the value of `uiState` was when it was created.

I assume this is a scoping issue, and the event handler is executed when it's created. I want it to check at the time of the click what the value of `uiState` is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but I really don't get want you are trying to do there :)

Comment: They're based on the HTML data properties, post your HTML for the button.

Comment: Do you expect each dropdown to have its own state? Currently you have a global `uiState` variable for all of them!

Comment: Please show us where the value of `uiState` is changed.

Comment: No, they don't need their own state. I'll add the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the element with `data-toggle="dropdown"` and remove this property when it changes state, eg:

```
$('#wx').attr('data-toggle',''); // Dropdown no longer shows
```

or

```
$('#wx').attr('data-toggle','dropdown'); // Dropdown shows again
```

The rest of the trigger continue as usual:

```
$('#wx').on('click', '.dropdown .dropdown-toggle', function (event) {
    if (uiState !== 'normal') {
        testClickCounter ++;
        console.log(testClickCounter);
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not address the problem. I've tried to explain it more clearly